# jQuery async/await Ajax call, without triggering an exception on HTTP <> 200?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, exception

I'm trying to make an async/await HTTP POST using jQuery like this:

```
    let response = await $.post({
        url: 'https://example.com/product/add',
        data: JSON.stringify({"foo":"bar"}),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
    });
```

I would then like to check the response code and determine which action to take based on it:

```
if( response.status === 200 ) {
    // Ok
}
else{
    // Something went wrong, inspect the response body for details
}
```

But it seems that `$.post()` throws an exception if the response status code is <> 200, which means I would have to wrap the whole thing in a `try...catch` block and do my error handling in the catch block instead.

I find it annoying to have to deal with exceptions for things like HTTP 500, *"Field 'foo' must be at least 4 characters"*.

Is there any way to make `$.post()` not throw an exception on status codes other than 200?

Answer (score 0):

use `$.post().always()` function.

**Description**: Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is either resolved or rejected.

(https://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/)